# kendoui need to have different currency formats in one column based on condition

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a column in Kendo UI that corresponds to currency. I would like to show the Data in dollars if the user is from US and Rupees if from India. Can we have two different formats for a single column based on a condition in Kendo UI.

I tried to bind the column like this but i do not get the Format required.

```c#
c.Bound(p => p.Amount).Template(p => 
   (p.Country == "India" ? p.Amount = p.AmountinRs : p.Amount = p.AmountinDls)
   ).Width(150);
```

PS: AmountinRs and AmountinDls is been declared with the required formats.

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

add culture js based on condition

this  js for sweden

then define

kendo.culture("sv-SE");

define row template in kendogrid

rowTemplate   : kendo.template(jQuery("#rowTemplate").html()),

where  #rowTemplate is div to show as row in grid

here is the sample

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <tr>
       your other field declaration here
         ......
         .....

       <td style="text-align:right;"><span class="book-price">#= kendo.format('{0:C}',price) #</span></td>
   </tr>
</script>
```